# Sort guild channels correctly discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, sorting, discord, discord.js

I'm making a command that when executed by an admin, the bot will list all of the channels in a specific category with the CORRECT order as we see them on discord. Whenever I ask for `<Category>.children.map(c => c.name)` I always get unordered elements with voice channels in the top of the array and same for stage channels. What I need is a function (here `sortChannels`)having the array (or the Collection of channels in the category) correctly ordered exactly like we see them on Discord. Here's my category :

[image: Category with text, voice and stage channels]

And i have :

```js
function sortChannels(channels){
    // What I need to figure out
}
let category = await guild.channels.fetch("935933604261592665")
let list = category.children
             .sort(sortChannels)
             .map(c => c.name)
             .join('\n')

message.channel.send(list)
```

I tried using [`position`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=position)
but it gives me the following result for each channel :

[image: RESULT]

Which doesn't help alot, what i'm looking for is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit late but this is the first result when googling so I wanted to give a proper answer.

It seems that Discord first puts the channels into categories, then sorts them first by their type, then by their position attribute.

This code seems to sort them the same way Discord's official client does, and puts them in a flat list, but you can very easily keep channels as children of each category:

```
//first we get channels without parents, this will most often be a category 
const categories = guild.channels.filter((channel) => !channel.parent_id);

categories.forEach((category) => {
      //then we get all channels that have this channel as a parent
  category.children = guild.channels.filter(
    (channel) => channel.parent_id == category.id
  );

  //then we sort the children by type and position

  category.children.sort((a, b) => b.type - a.type || b.position - a.position);
});

//then we sort the channels without parents by type and position)
categories.sort((a, b) => a.type - b.type || a.position - b.position);
guild.channels = [];
//then we store them as a flat array of channels
categories.forEach((channel) => {
  guild.channels.push(channel);
  if (channel.children) {
    guild.channels = guild.channels.concat(channel. Children);
  }
});
```

Then just add your custom position attribute and number them correctly

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the channel's position. GuildChannels have a `position` and `rawPosition` property. Although I don't know which represents the appeared position, try both.

```js
function sortChannels((a, b)){
    return a.position - b.position;
    // Or 
    return a.rawPosition - b.rawPosition;
}
```

[GuildChannel#position](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=position)

Comment: I used position and it seems like every channel type has their own position change, for example the voice channels have position 1 and 2, 3, 4, the text channel has 1 and the stage channel 1. I want to have the text channel 1, the voice channels 2, 3, 4, 5 and the stage channel 6 :/

Comment: It seems that `.position` is a getter that uses sorted channels (I don't know how exactly) and `.rawPosition` is straight from Discord API